# What is the Laurent series of $\frac{2}{z-1} - z$ in $1<|z|<2$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> What is the Laurent series of $\frac{2}{z-1} - z$ in $1<|z|<2$?

I can factor the first term to get
$$
f(z) = \frac{2}{z} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{z^n} - z
$$
where the series converges for $1<|z|$. This gives convergence on one side of the annulus. How do we go about finding the series for the other side?

Comment: This a precisely the Laurent series. The regular part has only one term $-z$.

Comment: @C.Dubussy I see it now. So is it true then that this Laurent series converges as long as $1 < |z| <\infty$ holds? Hence, it converges within the upper bound of the annulus in the question.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly that.